# Unwanted margin above div tag when adding a p tag inside

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Today when fiddling with some HTML and CSS, i stumbled upon a problem. When I put a paragraph tag inside of a div tag, it adds an ugly unwanted margin to the top of my div.

```
<div id="header">
<center>
    <p>Gavin Sadler.com</p>
</center>
```

```
body {
margin:0;
}
@font-face {
font-family: CoolveticaRg;
src: url(Coolvetica_Rg.otf);
}
#header {
width:%100;
height:100px;
background-color:grey;
margin-top:0;
}
#header{
margin-top:0px;
background-color:grey;
}
#header p {
font-family:CoolveticaRg, Arial;
}
```

I would appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the margin on the paragraph:

```
#header p {
    font-family: CoolveticaRg, Arial;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

On a side note, the `center` tag is deprecated. You should remove it and use CSS to style your elements. I've added the necessary code above to centre your text.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set this to you p element like this:

```
#header p{
    font-family:CoolveticaRg, Arial;
    margin: 0;
}
```

and it should fix your problem